# SVN checkout mac terminal

Tags: macos, svn, ssh, terminal

I have some issues to download a directory though mac's terminal.

On Windows:

```
 svn+ssh://netimage@xxxxxx.dk/home/netimage/svn/xxxxx.dk2
```

I've tried it though mac terminal via. this without luck.

```
 svn co http://xxxxxx/home/netimage/svn xxxxxx --username netimage
```

also tried

```
  svn co http://xxxxxx/home/netimage/svn/xxxxx.dk2 --username netimage
```

My password keyphrase is in "ssh add -K mypasswordkey.ppk"

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a Putty private key with Openssh. This won't work.

Solution: use one of the Putty programs (Puttygen?) to export your key into Openssh private key format. Then use that on your Mac.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `svn+ssh://` and not `http://` unless you also happen to be running Apache httpd on your server and configured it to serve Subversion.

What exactly is the issue when you try `svn+ssh://` on your Mac? What error are you getting? Are you getting any error. The error message will help us figure out what the issue could be.

Most likely, you don't have your ssh keys setup correctly.

On the Mac's command line terminal, run the program 'ssh-keygen`. This will generate the public/private keys you need.

Once you do that, you need to go to your Mac's `$HOME/.ssh` directory and look for the file `id_rsa.pub`. This is your Mac's *public* key. Take that, and  go to the system `xxxxxx.dk` and look in user `netimage` $HOME/.ssh`directory for an`authorized_keys` file. You will need your Mac's public key and add it to this file.

See if you can log in to your Subversion server via `ssh` without having to use your password. If you can do that, you have everything setup correctly. (Unless, of course, they've setup the server, so you can't log in with your account).

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
sudo svn --username user --password password co http://xxxx.xx/svn/projectname/
```